# Move a character from a cell to a new cell based on a numbered outline

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Am running Office Professional Plus 2013 on Windows 7. Have a matrix as depicted in the following image.

[image: excel matrix]

Matrix data is found in this [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PmVSJ1gXeoUdPA628dGE0C9tjK5_DjMsEAcPJkr3tiY/edit?usp=sharing).

Here are two facts about the matrix:

1. Column A is a numeric outline with outline levels ranging from 1 - 13.
2. Outline numbers are in order.

Here is an illustration about how the matrix is organized:

3. A4 (outline level 2) has a bracket in M4 where column M (labeled "L-02") corresponds to outline level 2.
4. A16 (outline level 6) has a bracket in I6 (eye 6) where column I (labeled "L-06") corresponds to outline level 6.
5. A7 (outline level 5) has *NO* bracket in J7 where column J (labeled "L-05") correspond to outline level 5.

**Need help in writing a formula or a VB script that would work as follows:**

6. For an *outline level column* with a bracket
7. FIND the next row where the outline in column A has a number of positions that are *less than* or *equal to* the number of positions for the current outline level
8. THEN move the bracket *from* its current cell in the outline column *to* the cell in the same column that is immediately before the solution to FIND

For example, take a look look at row 16. Need to:

9. FIND the next row where the number of positions for A16 is *less than* or *equal to* the number of positions for A16.
   That row is 21 because FIND would identify a cell (A21) that has less than the number of positions in A16.
10. Next, back up one row.
11. Then, move the bracket *from* I16 (eye 16; outline level 6) *to* I20.

The yellow cells in the image are examples of the cell to which the bracket in a column must be move.

**How to accomplish this in Excel?**

Ask me any question(s) about #1 - #11. For example, could the outline numbering scheme be changed to make it easier to parse and compare? Yes, the decimals could be removed.

In the `Google spreadsheet`, a sample set of cells with a red "x" indicate the positions to which the brackets should be moved.

Comment: In your sample sheet: shouldn't the `x` mark in `L11` be placed in `L10`?

Comment: if you mean row 694, the answer is no. Reason: 694 is child of 693. Further, 694 has 4 children, but these are terminal nodes in this section of the hierarchy - meaning they have no children. The same condition holds at 697. The balance of the `x` in column `L-11` are correct.

Comment: I mean cells `L11` and `L10`, so move `x` from row 11 one row up.

Comment: nope, because the outline indicates the next rows are children, and therefore a deeper level (i.e. previous level +1)

Comment: You description indicates that we should take the bracket from `L9`, find the first shorter or equal row (L11), go back one row (L10), and put the bracket there. So why is it in L11?

Comment: I've updated rows 689 - 705. I've placed an `x` in the appropriate location. Let me know if it's not clear or if I've made an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76705/discussion-between-user3964075-and-jay-gray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the algotithm, you can solve it using formulas. Here's my result:

[image]

Formula in `P2` (drag down to fill the column) is:

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))
```

It calculates number of `.` in current outline (you have `,` instead of `.` in some cases, so you should use `replace all` first to fix it).

Range `Q1:AD1`contains level number.

Formula in `Q2` (fill the entire range with it):

```
 =IF(AND($P2>$P3,MEDIAN($P2,$P3+1,Q$1)=Q$1),"]","")
```

It checks if current level is higher then the next one and if and displays `]` brackets for levels from (next row level +1)to (current row level).

The only difference between your sample and my result is in `L10` cell, but I think that the bracket from `L9` should be moved to `L10` (not `L11`) according to your algorithm.

Comment: TX. I'll try this out now and BBTY.

Comment: Have set the `LEN` equivalent to your image. Have copied the `IF` formula to `Q2`. However, when I copy `Q2` to the balance of the cells in the range (Q - AD and rows to end) I do not get the bracket that I see in your image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jay Gray can you add it to your sample google sheet? I could take a look

Comment: User error! I successfully duplicate your results. Now let me look at the possible errors that you've identified.

Comment: Brilliant. I now see errors from my manual exercise. FYI your solution is automation to build a JSON data structure in Excel. This will save me hours of work and eliminate errors. It will take me a while to convert the Excel structure to JSON and then test it. If I encounter problems then that I can't handle, will be back to you. ITMT, very nice solution - and no VB!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should find the column in which the bracket is located. Then define an array that starts in the same row and at the column you found +1. So in case of your row 16. It should start at J16 to the down right boundary of your dataset (O36 in this picture). 
Then search for the first time you encounter the bracket you can use a FOR loop on the number of rows, and nest a FOR loop on the columns here, with an if statement nested in that. Then when you identified that row you can use cells to copy the bracket into the new cell.

I just started writing scripts a few weeks ago, so I wouldn't be able to make this code precisely. But it would look something like this.

```
DIM Array as string
DIM totalrows as Thisworkbook.thisworkseet.count.rows

FOR rows x to totalrows
 FOR column X to totalcolumns
  IF cells(row,col) = Cells(cell you are looking up)
    THEN
     Cells (cell you are looking up) = (row -1, col) 
     Exit FOR
    End if
   Next column
  Next row
```

Comment: TX; I'll experiment and let you know the results.

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps there are some others that are able to write this code from scratch from the back of there mind, so an easier solution comes available.